# Rows with time & text strings

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, date-arithmetic

Below is my data in an excel Sample Data which has login and log out timings along with Text in some of the columns. I wanted to check if out time greater than a specified time say `2:00 AM`. I used the below formula (which I got from extendoffice.com)

`IF('Bio-Metric-Timings'!G72="","",IF('Bio-Metric-Timings'!G72>=(--"8:30 PM"),"Yes","No"))`

This formula is working fine but giving "Yes" value for the Text as well. I do not understand why. I only wanted "Yes" for columns with time and not text.

About Me: I like working on Excel but I do not have any coding or programming knowledge. I keep working on  Excel by visiting your website and others to simplify my work.

Appreciate your assistance on this dear experts !!!

[image: img]

Comment: I'm realizing this terminology mistake is fairly common: Are you sure that **bio-metric** is the correct term, or perhaps you mean **metrics**?  [`Biometric data`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biometrics) is *body measurements* such as fingerprint, palm veins, face recognition, DNA, palm print, hand geometry, iris recognition, retina, etc. `Metrics` is a method of measuring something, or the results obtained from this.

Comment: Your image isn't very descriptive.  Which cell is `G72`? Which cell is this formula in? What values are you hoping to get, in which cells?  ... **Also**, I would ***not*** recommend that site as a good source of tutorials -- nor any other site who's main objective is to sell you add-ins or books. There many better sites out there.)

Comment: @ashleedawg - also another term for Biostatistics (data about living organisms).

Comment: @Tim - you figure that's what this is?  Looks like work schedules to me, but of course can't say for sure with the limited sample.

Comment: Employees aren't alive ;-)  ?

Answer (score 1):

Kamal, if you are providing formula and looking for answer, then you should also provide column names and sheet names for better clarity.

I tried your formula. Though I am not getting the 'yes' as answer, but your text problem is solved. Instead of checking for blank (by using "" in your formula), just check if the cell value is a number.

Your answer:

```
IF(isnumber(('Bio-Metric-Timings'!G72),IF('Bio-Metric-Timings'!G72>=(--"8:30 PM"),"Yes","No"),"")
```

I didn't rename my sheet to Bio-Metric-Timings, plus I don't know which cell is G72, but this code should work.
Additionally, whenever out-time has text value, if you want to show a phrase, say, "Week off", then include it (Week off) in the last "" in the formula.